# Find all factors of 100

Tags: java, oop

I want to get all the integers that when you multiply them gives you 100. For example, 10*10=100.

```
package ex1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex1 {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;

        System.out.println("Please input a number");
        i = input.nextInt();

        for (int z = 1; z <= 10; z++) {
            float y;
            int x = 1;
            y = i;

            System.out.println("" + y / z + " * " + x * z + " = " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should post some text about the specific problem you are having. Code only questions are frowned upon.

Comment: YOur code and your question seem not really related

Comment: The name of the class, Ex1, seems to mean that you want someone else does your homework. You should do it yourself if you want to learn something useful

Comment: its not my homework and its my first time here all i want is when i multiply x*y=30 for example i want all the number for x and all the numbers for y that when you multiply them gives 30 and the number is not more than 100 or a decimal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give you all `integers` whose `product` is `equal` to `100`. *If instead of 100* you want `another` `number`, `simply change the 100` below to `any integer you want!`

```
for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j<=100; j++) {
    if (i*j==100) {
      System.out.println(i + " " + j);
    }
  }
}
```

here is everything in one class which you can compile and run:

```
class product{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j<=100; j++) {
         if (i*j==100) {
         System.out.println(i + " " + j);
         }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 100
2 50
4 25
5 20
10 10
20 5
25 4
50 2
100 1
```

Comment: this is the least efficient way to possibly solve this problem. for a number N it has to run N * N times.  you only need to loop from 1 to sqrt(N).  can you figure out why?

Comment: Yes of course it is not the most efficient way, but he does not request the most efficient way.. he requests a way to get the integers whose product is 100.. which is what my code does

Comment: granted, but i thought i'd give you a challenge :)  i bet if you worked at TGI Fridays you'd wear the bare minimum amount of flair

Comment: lol, I don't know about TGI Friday's flair but it is quite simple to understand why only going up until the sqrt(N) is enough, and it has something to do with the fact that sqrt(N)*sqrt(N) I suppose :D in which case sqrt(i*j)=sqrt(N) if you want to test my mental capabilities :D

Comment: I just had an idea that X*y=i so 2/2*x*y=i wont do a thing but actually when i did it (x*2)*(Y/2) it still = i so i made a loop that keeps adding 1 to the number 2 so i can get all the multiply numbers Its is just something i thought of ... not a homework but i had a problem with the double and int numbers

Comment: JAMES, you can just use int the entire time.  there is no need to use floats or doubles. i'd recommend using modulus instead of division to check for a factor.

-------
ADRCODER, i think you get it.  basically one of the factors must be less than or equal to sqrt(N).  so you just need to loop over those values and check it's modulus compared to N and it's a factor if it's modulus == 0.  (i.e. if it divides N with no remainder).  then you can calculate the other factor by division and trivially flip them if order matters without looping over the whole set (e.g. (5,20) and (20,5))

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a homework problem....

on paper try to figure out how you would go about this without using code, i.e. solve the example 10*10=100 by hand.  then write your code based on that logic.  one hint i have for the coding part is you should have a look at the modulus operator